# Executing jquery in "parent" page of a $.post request

Tags: jquery, post, parent

I have a form ( id = "selectors" ) on my **index.php** page, with only checkboxes, when I click a checkbox it loads a result page ( **index-main-list.php** ) in a div (id = main-list) of the index page using a $.post

```
$.post("index-main-list.php", $("#selectors").serialize(), function(data){
    $('#main-list').html(data);
});
```

This works fine, the issue is that in the index-main-list.php, that is displayed upon completion of the $.post request, I would like to include a link that would reset the #selectors form and check a checkbox of my choice.

But it looks like I can't do something as simple as:

```
$('#selectors')[0].reset();
$('input[id=topic]').attr('checked', true);
```

in my index-main-list.php page because it can't access the #selectors form located on index.php.

Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript only manipulates pages currently within the browser scope. "Other pages" are not accessible (browser doesn't know they exist atm). What you would need to do is make your link point to the page with certain GET/POST parameters set and then, either server side or after the page has loaded, set the checkboxes to the expected positions.

Comment: Thanks, I see, so even if it's on the same page, if I load the content in a div using a $.post callback, it won't work? 

If so, is it possible to make a link containing POST parameters? for some reason I can't mess the url, so using GET is not really an option.

Thanks!